# Why on earth would you call SSRF and XXE a type of injection attack?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability

I've just received a pen test report and these idiots have included vulnerabilities like SSRF and XXE under the injection heading! This is nonsense they have some, but not all, characteristics of injection attacks.

In a typically injection attack, such as SQL injection, untrusted data is combined with a trusted query by string concatenation, then the result is passed to a function that parses it - a dangerous sink

For SSRF, XXE, and some other issues the untrusted data is passed directly to a dangerous sink. There is no string concatenation so obviously they are totally different.

Remediation advice for typical injection flaws is generally around how to safely use untrusted data within a query, such as using a parameterized query. Remediation advice for SSRF and XXE is typically around configuration to make the dangerous sink safe, such as disabling external entities or using a proxy on an isolated network segment. The different remediation approach proves they are a different category.

How can people get away with this? They even have accreditations!

Answer (score -1):

I think your thought process is flawed here. Vulnerabilities aren't classified by their remediation approaches.

What lies at the heart of injection attacks? Untrusted data. What is the root cause of SSRF and XXE? Untrusted data. There is no rule that states injection attacks can only occur when data is concatenated.

SSRF and XXE both rely on untrusted data being accepted and used by the backend system in some fashion regardless of whether or not it gets concatenated with additional data. Someone is 'injecting' untrusted data into your systems in both of these attacks.

Remediation for injection attacks and SSRF and XXE all include input validation among other strategies.